# Creating custom.css in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a class "dropdown-menu" in twitter bootstrap eg.`<ul class="dropdown-submenu">`.
As you observe there is an arrow right to it.How to set the color of arrow to dark when hovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way :

For Dropdown-menu onhover color change:

```
.navbar .nav li.dropdown > a:hover .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown > a:focus .caret {
border-bottom-color: red;/*change color to your liking*/
border-top-color: red;/*change color to your liking*/
}
```

Change color of caret when active(Dropdown menu) :

```
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle .caret {
border-bottom-color: #008745;/*change color*/
border-top-color: #008745;/*change color*/
 }
```

For Dropdown Sub menu

```
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000000;/*change here */
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
content: " ";
display: block;
float: right;
height: 0;
margin-right: -10px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 0;
}
```

Dropdown submenu onHover color change :

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after{
      border-left-color:#fff; /* change the color to anything of your choice*/

  }
```

The default color of caret is set here and can be changed where mentioned below:

```
.caret {
border-left: 4px solid transparent;
border-right: 4px solid transparent;
border-top: 4px solid #FFFFFF; /* change the color to anything of ur liking */
content: "";
display: inline-block;
height: 0;
vertical-align: top;
width: 0;
}
```

Comment: he is asking for change icon color in bootstrap that use a image for icons

Comment: I know Sahil what he is asking for ... caret color can be set the way I have mentioned .

Comment: thank you for giving suggestion @SahilPopli.. I really appreciate your effort.,

Comment: @user2058595 did ya check the answer

Answer (score 0):

just switch over the glyphicons image?

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover{
  i{
    background-image: url("../images/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
  }
```

just download colored icon image file from [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=glyphicons-halflings-white.png&hl=en&newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=qeI1Uc6CBs-dkgWHlICICA&ved=0CD0QsAQ&biw=1024&bih=651#hl=en&newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=glyphicons-halflings.png&oq=glyphicons-halflings.png&gs_l=img.3...972.972.0.1736.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..5.img.TzWWbTvulkA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.dGI&fp=e53273fdaeca0e75&biw=1024&bih=651) or glyphicons or change yourself in photoshop

Comment: He is not asking to change any glyphicons neither he mentioned about it . Just a color change .. check my solution